# Operator overload in class templates and friendship

Tags: c++, templates

Suppose I have a small class template as below

```
template<typename T> class SillyClass {
public:

  SillyClass(const T val);
  SillyClass(const SillyClass& other);

private:

  T data;

};
```

Now I add the following <strike>definitions</strike> declarations:

```
template<typename T> class SillyClass {
public:

  SillyClass(const T val);
  SillyClass(const SillyClass& other);

  SillyClass<T> operator+ (const SillyClass& other);
  SillyClass<T> operator+ (const T& val);

private:

  T data;

};
```

and now (after I write the appropriate definitions) I can do things like

```
SillyClass<int> a(1);
SillyClass<int> b(a);
SillyClass<int> c = a + b;
SillyClass<int> d = a + 3;
```

So far, so good. However, to be able to write something like

```
SillyClass<int> e = 3 + a;
```

I found that must add the following declaration to my class

```
  template<typename T2> friend SillyClass<T2> operator+ 
    (const T2& val, const SillyClass<T2>& other);
```

so it now reads

```
template<typename T> class SillyClass {
public:

  SillyClass(const T val);
  SillyClass(const SillyClass& other);

  SillyClass<T> operator+ (const SillyClass& other);
  SillyClass<T> operator+ (const T& val);

  template<typename TT> SillyClass<TT> friend operator+ 
    (const TT& val, const SillyClass<TT>& other);

private:

  T data;

};
```

I didn't find this in a book and I'd like some help to understand what's happening on this last declaration. For instance, with what is my class being befriended here? Why the additional template declaration? What alternatives do I have in terms of different declarations that lead to the same result (being able to perform 3+a, say)?

Thanks.

Comment: `friend` declares something that isn't actually part of the class - think about why you'd need an extra template parameter if you declared it after the last `};`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> with what is my class being befriended here? Why the additional template declaration?

The following expression declared inside your class is a [friend declaration](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/friend):

```
template<typename TT> SillyClass<TT> friend operator+ 
    (const TT& val, const SillyClass<TT>& other);
```

The above expression declares your class a friend with a family of overloaded `operator+`s that take as their left-hand-side parameter a type `TT` and as their right-hand-side an object `SillyClass<TT>`. Note though that this is a declaration and not a definition. That is, in order for this to work the template overloaded `operator+`, must be defined.

> What alternatives do I have in terms of different declarations that
>   lead to the same result (being able to perform 3+a, say)?

For binary operators in order for them to be symmetric must be declared outside the class definition as free functions, and in order to have access to the private members of their class parameters you declare them as a friend function of the respective class.

Based on these lines I would go along with the following implementation:

```
template<typename T> class SillyClass {
  T data;
public:
  SillyClass(const T val) : data(val) {}
  SillyClass(const SillyClass& other) : data(other.data) {}

  template<typename T1, typename T2>
  friend SillyClass<typename std::common_type<T1, T2>::type> 
  operator+(SillyClass<T1> const &lsh, SillyClass<T2>& rhs);

  template<typename T1, typename T2>
  friend SillyClass<typename std::common_type<T1, T2>::type> 
  operator+(SillyClass<T1> const &lsh, T2 const &rhs);

  template<typename T1, typename T2>
  friend SillyClass<typename std::common_type<T1, T2>::type> 
  operator+(T1 const &rhs, SillyClass<T2> const &rsh);
};

template<typename T1, typename T2>
SillyClass<typename std::common_type<T1, T2>::type> 
operator+(SillyClass<T1> const &lhs, SillyClass<T2>& rhs) {
  return SillyClass<typename std::common_type<T1, T2>::type>(lhs.data + rhs.data);
}

template<typename T1, typename T2>
SillyClass<typename std::common_type<T1, T2>::type> 
operator+(SillyClass<T1> const &lhs, T2 const &rhs) {
  return SillyClass<typename std::common_type<T1, T2>::type>(lhs.data + rhs);
}

template<typename T1, typename T2>
SillyClass<typename std::common_type<T1, T2>::type> 
operator+(T1 const &lhs, SillyClass<T2> const &rhs) {
  return SillyClass<typename std::common_type<T1, T2>::type>(rhs.data + lhs);
}
```

[**Live Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/01220901f850daee)

Comment: Thanks! Also +1 for the live demo. That's cool. Thank you for the summary. I was only finding scattered information about this.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of only declaring your operator in class, you can *define* the `friend` operator inside your class:

```
SillyClass<T> friend operator+(const T& val, const SillyClass<T>& other)
{
    // define it here
}
```

This way, for each instance of your class, a corresponding `friend` will be generated. The whole thing works based on something called *friend name injection*.

Now back to your problem. If you just use an in-class declaration

```
friend operator+(const T& val, const SillyClass<T>& other);
```

and then outside your class you define

```
template<typename T>
friend operator+(const T& val, const SillyClass<T>& other)
```

you'll get a linker error. Why? Because suppose `T=int` when you instantiate the class. Then the declaration in your class will read as

```
friend operator+(const int& val, const SillyClass<int>& other);
```

and will be a better match than the above template definition whenever you invoke your `operator+` on `SillyClass<int>` and some `int`. So the linker won't be able to find the definition of the required `int` instantiation, hence a linker error. On the other hand, the solution I proposed at the beginning of the answer *guarantees* a corresponding definition for *every* type, so it will work without any headaches.

Comment: Thanks. Your explanation about the linker error was very appreciated.